# Prevent stacking of AJAX-requests

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I've got a problem which I can't seem to solve.

I'm currently implementing a an AJAX-function similar to the one Twitter uses - that fetch new posts on scrolling.

The jQuery looks something like this:

```
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
                $('div#ajaxloader').show();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "loader.php?lastid=" + $(".container:last").attr("id"),
                    success: function(html){
                        if(html){
                            $("#main").append(html);
                            $('div#ajaxloader').hide();
                        }else{
                            $('div#ajaxloader').html('No more posts to show.');
                        }
                    }                   
                });
            }
        });
```

Now the problem; if the user scrolls really fast and the database is doing it's work quickly - the jQuery doesn't seem to be able to send the correct id as a query fast enough - which results in double-posts.

Anyone have a good idea on how to prevent this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try This:

```
  var runningRequest = 0;
  $(window).scroll(function(){
        if(runningRequest <1){
        if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
            runningRequest++;
            $('div#ajaxloader').show();
            $.ajax({
                url: "loader.php?lastid=" + $(".container:last").attr("id"),
                success: function(html){
                    runningRequest--;
                    if(html){
                        $("#main").append(html);
                        $('div#ajaxloader').hide();
                    }else{
                        $('div#ajaxloader').html('No more posts to show.');
                    }
                }
                error: function(){runningRequest--;}                   
            });
        }
        }
    });
```

Comment: you also could put the runningRequest--; into the complete: part of the ajax request instead of the success and error part.

Comment: That did the trick! Very clever - and rather simple =) Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I was writing this exact semaphore answer ¬¬

Comment: Heh, looks like you beat me to the punch. I don't understand the use of an incremented/decremented integer as opposed to a boolean, though.

Comment: The thing i was using here is called closure. using a fariable inside a function declaration without any further reference. this is a speccial language feature only vew languages provide. also it is the cause of many problems so be careful with closures.

Comment: @JAAulde the thing is that using a boolean you could have problems with paralell execution. if you do it fast enough the browser could create 2 instances of the function call. so if i use an integer and ask if the integer is < 1 and it is 0 at that time in both functions and the execute in a parallel way then i have max 2 ajax calls and all calls that come later will be dismissed untill ALL BOTH calls are done. if i use a bool then one returning call could open the barrier and you would do another ajax call while one is still running.

Comment: @ITroubs - yes, I see what you're saying. I'd have to play around some to see if what you're suggesting is really a concern in such a limited scope. But scrolling _is_ a fast and heavily-hit event, so it's a good thing to stay on top of.

Comment: @ITroubs - that scenario's not possible in JavaScript, because it's single-threaded. As long as you're not using something like a setTimeout in the middle of all that, a boolean would work fine.

Comment: You want to use --runningRequsts or ++runninRequests. Preorder calculation is faster than Inorder.

Answer (score 1):

I would set a boolean to true right before making my request, and whenever the request completes I'd set it back to false. Then I'd wrap the code that makes the request in a check for whether that value is true or false.  I'd also add a bool that tells me whether I should even bother making a request--no sense in requesting if the last request came back empty (unless, perhaps, the data set could change since the last request).  Either way, here's the code I'd start with:

```
( function( global )
{
    var $ = global.jQuery,
        $win = $( global ),
        $doc = $( global.document ),
        $ajaxLoader = $( 'div#ajaxloader' ),
        $main = $( '#main' ),
        requestInProgress = false,
        outOfPosts = false;

    $win.scroll( function()
    {
        if( ! requestInProgress &&
            ! outOfPosts &&
            $win.scrollTop() === $doc.height() - $win.height()
          )
        {
            requestInProgress = true;

            $ajaxLoader.show();

            $.ajax( {
                url: 'loader.php',
                data: {
                    lastid: $( '.container:last' ).attr( 'id' )
                },
                success: function( html )
                {
                    if( html )
                    {
                        $main.append( html );
                        $ajaxLoader.hide();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        outOfPosts = true;
                        $ajaxLoader.html( 'No more posts to show.' );
                    }
                },
                complete: function()
                {
                    requestInProgress = false;
                }
            } );
        }
    } );
}( window ) );
```

Comment: Thanks you very much, quite the same as @ITroubs answer - already accepted his answer though.

Comment: No prob. Do read my response and code, though. I've suggested a check to stop polling for data if a request comes back without any data (if it fits with the mentality of what you're doing). I've also made your code more performant in that I fixed all your extra API calls which requery the DOM for what you already have.